# format databound field according to the value- ASP

Tags: asp.net, boundfield

I have a data bound field say "Role"
The values in the database for its corresponding field contains 1,2,3.

I need to know whether i can format that databound field according to the value
for eg:
if 1 is the value, it should show "Admin".
if 2 is the value, it should show "Support".
if 3 is the value, it should show "User".

can i use DataFormatString for this purpose??

PLS HELP.

Comment: friends, pls add some comments atleast

Comment: show some code. How are you displaying it right now

Answer (score 0):

One approach is get this value before you display it e.g from database or codebehind

```
Select 
Role,
CASE
   WHEN Role = 1 THEN 'Admin'
   WHEN Role = 2 THEN 'Support'
   WHEN Role = 3 THEN 'User'
END RoleDescription
FROM MyTable
```

Output is below. You can use the RoleDescription value instead of Role

```
Role      RoleDescription
----------------------------------
1         Admin
2         Support
1         Admin
1         Admin
3         User
```

Comment: tht is good, but u can't edit the data. I found another solution. See below. :P

Answer (score 0):

Atlast i found a WAY.. anyways thanks codingbiz!!

Make that field as a templatefield and edit that template. In the item template view, remove the label field and insert a dropdown. there you manually add the items with its values and bind selected value to the field (here role).

steps..
Select item > convert it to TemplateField >

Edit template > select that template (ItemTemplate) > 
Change label to dropdown > add items to drop down with its value > bind selected value property to the original data field..

THATZ IT!!